# getting the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <module name> for everything I install via pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pip, pycharm

I'm very new to this and I'm sure I'm missing something here, but here goes:

I've installed a few packages via pip in cmd, let's take sklearn for example:

> pip install sklearn

The installation goes fine. I get a message:

> Successfully installed sklearn-0.0.

I then go to pycharm and start my code with

> import sklearn

I run the code and get the following error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'.

This is just an example, it happens to every package I install, so I'm assuming it's something with the installation path (or something else that's basic which I don't understand).

I'm using: 
* python V 3.7.2 (I've read a few posts about similar issues and many mentioned it's due to both python 2 and 3 being installed on your comp, but no other versions of python are installed on my comp)
* pycharm V 2018.3.4 community edition
* Windows 10 pro

Since I suspect it's related to the path, here is where pip install packages for me:

> c:\users\shay\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages

I looked for more basic packages that come with python to try and see where they are, and found that they are here:

> C:\Users\Shay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib

I've added both folders to my variable path in windows.

I've also tried to copy the content of the installation folder (top one, ends with "site-packages") and pasted it to the bottom folder (ends with "Lib"), but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

I expect to be able to run "import sklearn" (and other packages) after I install it via pip, but instead I get the above mentioned error.

Comment: Add the python interpreter you are installing your packages to, in PyCharm

Comment: Hi Devesh, as per pycharm, I'm using "C:\Users\Shay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe"
The pip installs the packages to:
c:\users\shay\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages

Comment: and when you open that interpreter and run `import sklearn` what do you see?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your first question, edited my answer above.
As mentioned in the question, the error is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'"

Comment: Then the python interpreter you are installing the packages is not the same as your PyCharm interpreter, Change your Pycharm python interpreter, take a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-language-interpreter.html on how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are execute that command at sys level. So if your default python is 2.7.12. Then If you run pip install in cmd then it will work for system level.

But in pycharm it always create a virtual environment,So that this error occurs.

So either you can run your program using cmd or you have to setup your virtual environment first and install all the python library in virtual environment and then run your program.

Comment: So in order to use pycharm I'll have to create a virtual environment?
Can you please direct me to a page that shows how something like this is done?

Many thanks,

Comment: Ok, got it, installed the packages via pycharm instead of via pip in CMD.
Thanks!